# Adding numbers from a list (e.g. asdf125dkf will return 8)

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I need a function that will take in a list of characters and numbers, and then return the numbers added up (ignoring the characters). This is what I have so far:

```
(define (adder lst)
   (cond
     ((null? lst)
       0)
     ((number? (car lst))
      (+(adder (car lst)) (adder (cdr lst))))
     ((char? (car lst))
      ((adder(cdr lst))))
     ))

(display (adder '(asd12sdf)))
```

Running it on codepad.org just displays void. I know the code is wrong because it looks wrong, but I have no idea how to fix it...  How do I have the function keep track of the first number it finds and add it to the next one it finds, while skipping all characters?

Comment: +1 for being the model homework question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second cond case, there's no reason to run `adder` on `(car lst)`.  Just adding `(car list)` itself to the recursive step should work.

For the last line, don't test `(char? (car lst))`.  Just make the last line the `else` clause, meaning that anything BUT a number will go to the else line.

The reason you're getting void is because your input doesn't satisfy *any* of the `cond` conditions, and you have no `else`, so the answer is nothing (i.e. `(void)`).

The last mistake is in the input you're giving it.  `'(asd12sdf)` is literally a list with **one** symbol named "asd12sdf".  I think you want to give it `'(a s d 1 2 s d f)` (a list of 6 symbols and 2 numbers) which should result in 3.  Notice that there's a very important difference between the symbol `'a` and the character `#\a`.

It looks like you have the logic down, so your problem doesn't seem to be functional languages, just Scheme's syntax.

**Edit:** and in the last line, you have `((adder(cdr lst)))` which has one too many parens wrapped around it.  That will cause Scheme to attempt to evaluate the result of adder (which is a number) as a procedure (error!).

Answer (score 0):

You should observe that this function is more or less `sum` which can be defined simply by using `fold`.

```
(define (adder lst)
   (fold + 0 lst))
```

What does fold do? Basically, it's defined like so:

```
(define (fold f initial lst)
  (if (null? lst)
     initial
     (fold f (f (car lst) initial) (cdr lst))))
```

(In other words, it calls f, a function of 2 arguments, on each element of lst, using the car of the lst as the first argument, and the accumulated result as the second argument to f.)

The issue here which you need to address is that + doesn't know how to operate on non-numeric values. No problem, you've already dealt with that. What happens if it's a character instead? Well, you're not adding anything to the total value, so replace it with a 0. Therefore, your solution is as simple as:

```
(define (adder lst)
   (fold your-new-protected-+ 0 lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp:

```
(reduce #'+ '(1 #\a #\b 2 1 2 #\c #\d 4)
        :key (lambda (item) (if (numberp item) item 0)))
```

or

```
(loop for item in '(1 #\a #\b 2 1 2 #\c #\d 4)
      when (numberp item) sum item)
```